# Replacing ' by \'

Tags: regex, r

How to convert `'` in a string to `\'` in R?

Example: from `Bob's` to `Bob\'s`

Comment: @Sachin: R is a programming language (with quite a few questions on SO, in fact I only remember it because I see R questions here from time to time).

Answer (score 6):

You have to escape the backslash.

```
> gsub("'","\\\\'","Bob's")  # R prints with the escape embedded
[1] "Bob\\'s"
> cat(gsub("'","\\\\'","Bob's"),"\n")  # But it's just a single backslash
Bob\'s
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> gsub("'", "\\\\'", "foo's bar's")
[1] "foo\\'s bar\\'s"
```

The results looks like the backslashes are double-escaped, but if you check with nchars() you'll see that it's actually just single backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out:

`gsub("\'", "\\\'", "Bob's")`

What confused me was that the backslash isn't displayed.